# Make a bullet shape around model in libgdx

Tags: java, collision-detection, libgdx, models, bullet-physics

How do I make a btBoxShape around a Model or ModelInstance in Libgdx?
This is my code:

```
modelInstance.calculateBoundingBox(boundingBox);
collisionShape = new btBoxShape(boundingBox.getDimensions(tempVector3).scl(.5f));
```

This works and creates a box of the right size but it is offset from the model. I cant figure out how to make it around the model and not offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a `btMotionState` to synchronize model and bullet transforms. You use it like this ([example taken from LibGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bullet-Wrapper---Using-models)):

```
// Create your own implementation
public class MyMotionState extends btMotionState {
    Matrix4 transform;

    @Override
    public void getWorldTransform (Matrix4 worldTrans) {
        worldTrans.set(transform);
    }

    @Override
    public void setWorldTransform (Matrix4 worldTrans) {
        transform.set(worldTrans);
    }
}

// Then attach it to your body
btRigidBody body = ...;
ModelInstance instance = ...;
MyMotionState motionState = new MyMotionState();
motionState.transform = instance.transform;
body.setMotionState(motionState);
```

The [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bullet-physics) is a very good place to get information about how to use the wrapper. You should also check out [Xoppa's blog on the subject](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/using-the-libgdx-3d-physics-bullet-wrapper-part1/) as he goes into more in-depth solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting it to offset with scaling dimensions with 0.5f . Try not to scale it 
or just create new vector3 at {0,0,0} .

```
collisionShape = new btBoxShape(boundingBox.getDimensions(tempVector3));
```

Comment: The scaling is because the parameters for the btBoxShape are half extents. I have tried making a new vector without scaling and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide screen capture.